# Design time error in custom control in compact framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I am writing an extension for standard ListView control in compact framework (VS2008, target platform - Windows Mobile 6.1, C#).

The class is currently pretty much empty, only having one method override (see the code below). The problem I encounter is this: when I have my control on a form with at least ListViewItem the control fails to initialize when opened in design time.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Smart Device class library project.
2. Add a new class `ListViewEx : System.Windows.Forms.ListView`
3. Override the `OnHandleCreated` method:

   ```
   protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnHandleCreated(e);
   }
   ```
4. Add the file `DesignTimeAttributes.xmta` to the project:

   ```
   <Classes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/03/SmartDevices/XMTA.xsd">
       <Class Name="CompleteNamespace.ListViewEx">
           <DesktopCompatible>true</DesktopCompatible>
           <DesignTimeVisible>true</DesignTimeVisible>
       </Class>
   </Classes>
   ```

   *(Replace the `CompleteNamespace` with the correct namespace.)*
5. Build the project.
6. Create a new Smart Device Application project in the same solution.
7. Drag the `ListBoxEx` on the `Form1` from the toolbox.
8. Add one column and one `ListViewItem` with arbitrary text.
9. Set `View` property of the `ListViewEx` to `Details`.
10. Save, rebuild everything and close the form designer tab.
11. Reopen form designer.

At this point I would expect to see my list view with one item in it. Instead VS throws an error:

> The control Microsoft.CompactFramework.Design.HeaderControl has thrown
>   an unhandled exception in the designer and has been disabled.
>
> Exception:
>
> InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
>   Parameter name: index
>
> Stack trace:
>   at Microsoft.CompactFramework.Design.HeaderControl.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
>   at Microsoft.CompactFramework.Design.HeaderControl.WndProc(Message& m)

When I press `OK`, the ListViewEx placeholder looks like this [image: the error text which is displayed in place of the normal control content]

Furthermore, if I leave the form open for some time (about a minute) VS also throws a new error:

> Code generation for property 'Items' failed.  Error was: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
>
> Parameter name: index'

Some notes:

1. If the `OnHandleCreated` is removed the control works as expected.
2. The control does not fail to initialize when there are no items in it.
3. The control works fine in run time.

Now, I understand that the obvious workaround solution would be to avoid overriding the `OnHandleCraeted`. But I want to execute some native windows methods that require HWND handle as a part of initialization routine. And `OnHandleCreated` seems to be the right place to do so. (The control fails with only having `base.OnHandleCreated` in the body of the method)

So the question is: is there a way to keep the `OnHandleCreated` override and make the control work in design time? Or another one: when and where is the best to execute native windows methods which require HWND handle?

Comment: Certainly smells like a bug and moving the initialization like you've done is probably the only good way around it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I managed to get things working. I've put my initialization to `OnParentChanged`. I know it may get called more than once and I got i covered.

Smells like a dirty hack though.